# Multiple requests using WebClient Spring WebFlux

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I am trying to make requests using WebClient in parallel, but I have no clue how to go about that,
because no matter what I do, the code is not waiting for requests to finish. If I execute just one request though (Commented fragment), everything works fine. Can someone help me with that?

```
@RequestMapping(method = [RequestMethod.POST], path = ["/upload/{batchId}"])
fun uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") file: Mono<FilePart>,
                       @PathVariable("batchId") batchId:String,
                       @RequestHeader("FILE-SIZE") fileSize:Int): Mono<ServiceResponse> {
    val webClient = WebClient.create(commandEndpoint)
    // return webClient.put().uri(seriesPath).retrieve().bodyToMono(String::class.java).map { ServiceResponse(it,0) }
    return file.map{it.transferTo(Paths.get(storagePath,"excel"))}
        .map{excelWorkbookToMetadata(WorkbookFactory.create(Paths.get(storagePath,"excel").toFile()))}
        .flatMapMany{Flux.fromIterable(it)}
        .flatMap {
            it.transactionId = batchId
            when (it) {
                is SeriesMetadata -> webClient.put().uri(seriesPath,it.id)
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(it))
                    .retrieve()
                    .onStatus({ it == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST },{
                        println("ERROR")
                        Mono.error(RuntimeException("blah")) }).toMono()
                else -> Mono.error(NotImplementedError(""))
            }

        }
        .collectList()
        .map {ServiceResponse(batchId, it.size*2) }
}
```

Comment: Try .block() at the end to make it waiting, also you can specify a duration in the block if you want

Comment: can't use block in netty threads. Maybe I should execute that logic in a separate thread?

Comment: dont ever use block in reactive applications, blocking will halter execution and hog threads. Very bad @eduPeeth

Comment: @quirell, Did you check `Mono`'s `zip` & `zipWhen`

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-java.util.function.Function-reactor.core.publisher.Mono...-

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zipWhen-java.util.function.Function-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems, that collectList() filters out empty mono that are returned in case the body of the response is empty. The solution is basically, either to use Mono.defaultIfEmpty() method, or change retrieve() to exchange() which always returns something. At least that's what helped me.